# Piping LAME and SOX togteher in a shell script. Is it possible?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm using the following in a shell script  :

```
##For ease of understanding I'll declare the $1 variable here even though it's actually arriving remotely via an ssh2_exec command.

$1="my.mp3"

lame --decode /root/incoming/shows/$1 - | /root/incoming/stereo_tool_cmd_64 - - -s /usr/incoming/settings/setting.sts | lame -b 128 - /root/incoming/processing/$1;
```

So what is happening? LAME decodes the mp3 file to wav, then it is piped to STEREO TOOL (audio processing script), then back to LAME where it's re-encoded as an mp3 file and the result is written to a different directory.

This all works great but I want to use SOX during this pipe to remove all silence from the start and end of the file, while it's in it's decoded wav state, before hitting STEREO TOOL.

I've tried this but it doesn't work (SOX breaks the pipe) :

```
lame --decode /root/incoming/shows/$1 - | sox silence 1 0.1 0.1% reverse silence 1 0.1 0.1% reverse | /root/incoming/stereo_tool_cmd_64 - - -s /usr/incoming/settings/setting.sts | lame -b 128 - /root/incoming/processing/$1;
```

I know the standard way to use SOX would be :

```
sox input.wav output.wav silence 1 0.1 0.1% reverse silence 1 0.1 0.1% reverse;
```

But I can't declare the wav file here as it's being created on the fly by LAME.

Is what I'm trying to do impossible or is there a solution that will allow me to do this?

Comment: try moving the `-` indicator for stdin from  `lame` to `sox - output.wav sile...`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter what do I declare as the output.wav though? That's not being defined anywhere as LAME is creating the wav temporarily?

Comment: Why not have sox decode the MP3 itself?

Comment: I'm really only going on a general usage of `-` to indicate to a program "read from stdin" (rather than a named file). So that covers  your input (per your sox example). The next argument seems to be the output file, so as I have written (not a sure thing!), `lame ....  | sox - output.sav silence ...|....` might work. Or you'll have to move the output.wav to the correct place in the pipeline. I don't have a way of reproducing your exact case, so just trying to offer general observations based on lots of years futzing with cranky apps ;-[)  ... Good luck!

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams This entire routine is repeated multiple times on different files constantly. Using LAME to decode it deletes the wav it's generated once the final mp3 has been created. If I do it with SOX i'll end up with 2 massive wav files for every process (each file can be 2hrs long), that I would then have to programatically delete after each routine. Or can SOX work the same way that LAME does?

Comment: @shellter cheers bro, will have a play with that!

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the input(pipe)/output(pipe) to sox this way:

```
sox -t wav - -t wav -
```

So the complete line is:

```
lame --decode /root/incoming/shows/$1 - | sox -t wav - -t wav - silence 1 0.1 0.1% reverse silence 1 0.1 0.1% reverse | /root/incoming/stereo_tool_cmd_64 - - -s /usr/incoming/settings/setting.sts | lame -b 128 - /root/incoming/processing/$1;
```

However please note: I am not able to test stereo_tool_cmd_64. Without this element it works fine for me.